# How to add a new API endpoint route in strapi?

Tags: strapi

I'm new to strapi and backend in general.

I have created a content type called post and it is accessible by this route `/posts/:id` by default. However I also want this post to be accessible in this route `/posts/:slug` .
I tried adding a new route in the `routes.json` file but when I visit the route, it returns a 404 error.

How do I achieve this?

EDIT:

My `routes.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "routes": [{
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/posts",
      "handler": "Post.find",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/posts/count",
      "handler": "Post.count",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/posts/:id",
      "handler": "Post.findOne",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/posts/:slug",
      "handler": "Post.findOne",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/posts",
      "handler": "Post.create",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "PUT",
      "path": "/posts/:id",
      "handler": "Post.update",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
    {
      "method": "DELETE",
      "path": "/posts/:id",
      "handler": "Post.delete",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What does your `routes.json` look like?

Comment: I just duplicated the route for id and put in slug

https://pastebin.com/xYfQPKkH

Comment: How are you 'visiting' the route? What are you typing to access it? It's likely that your handler doesn't know what `slug` means. You'll need to create another handler. Also, why do you need to replicate the functionality of an existing route? What's your use case for this?

Comment: I'm visiting this url -  `http://localhost:1337/posts/perfect-simplicity`

`perfect-simplicity` is the slug of a specific post. I can get the same post when I access it with the id url like this - `http://localhost:1337/posts/2`

Comment: The logic behind the handler `Post.findOne` does not understand what `perfect-simplicity` means as it's trying to locate the post via a unique identifier given by strapi when it was created. Nonetheless, even if you created a new handler to cater for your requirements, it would not be best practice as (I assume) your `slug` is not a unique identifier (many posts can be created with the same `slug`). If you want to create a new endpoint, you'll need to create a handler for it too

Comment: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/guides/controllers.html#how-to-create-a-controller

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that your new `slug` endpoint uses the same handler as the one that finds posts by their unique identifier (an incremented number given to each post). So it doesn't have a clue about `perfect-simplicity` as it's expecting a numerical value.

In order to fix your issue, you'll need to create a new handler/ controller for your endpoint.

Here's a link to the Strapi documentation:
https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/guides/controllers.html#adding-endpoints

You were correct in the creation of your route:

Path - **`./api/hello/config/routes.json`**

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/hello",
      "handler": "Hello.index"
    }
  ]
}
```

It's just your handler that needs to be changed.

Path — **`./api/hello/controllers/Hello.js`**

```
module.exports = {
  // GET /hello
  index: async ctx => {
    ctx.send('Hello World!');
  },
};
```

Just as a note, as mentioned in the documentation:

> A route handler can only access the controllers defined in the `./api/**/controllers` folders.

---

That aside, you shouldn't really be using `slug` as I don't think it's a unique identifier in your posts (unless you're preventing users from creating posts with the same `perfect-simplicity` slug). It isn't best practice. You'll likely encounter a lot of issues in the future should you allow posts to be accessed via their `slug` values.

Answer (score 5):

if your need is to be able to find an Article by `slug`, I suggest you to update the `findOne` controller function by using this documentation - https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/controllers.html#core-controllers

Here is the custom function

**Path —** `./api/article/controllers/Article.js`

```js
const { sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');

module.exports = {
  async findOne(ctx) {
    //check if the params id is an id or a slug
    const {id} = ctx.params;

    // if you use MongoDB database
    // we are validating that the id match ObjectID format
    if (id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
      const entity = await strapi.services.article.findOne(ctx.params);
      return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.article });
    }

    // if you use SQL database
    // we check if the id is a valid number
    if (parseInt(id) == id) {
      const entity = await strapi.services.article.findOne(ctx.params);
      return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.article });
    }

    // findOne function works only with IDs
    // so we find all and get first entry by using slug
    const [entity] = await strapi.services.article.find({slug: id});
    return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.article });
  }
};
```